# Why ActiveRecord not receiving these getting aggregate functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Doing a query with aggregate functions directly on ActiveRecord with Postgres seems to be working ok.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("
  SELECT created_at::date as date, 
    sum(item1_count) as sum_item1, 
    sum(item2_count) as sum_item2,
    sum(item3) as sum_item3 from items 
  GROUP by 
    created_at::date ORDER BY date desc").to_a
```

And returns something like this which is ok.

```
[
  {
              "date" => "2014-01-23",
         "sum_item1" => "3239",
        "sum_item2" => "90",
      "sum_item3" => "0.00000"
  },
  {
              "date" => "2014-01-22",
         "sum_item1" => "1981",
        "sum_item2" => "19",
      "sum_item3" => "0.00000"
  }
]
```

The problem is when trying to do the same using scopes, for instance.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :myscope, -> { 
    select("created_at::date as date, sum(item1_count) as sum_item1, 
      sum(item2_count) as sum_item2, 
      sum(item3) as sum_item3")
   .group("created_at::date")
   .order("date desc") }
end
```

The result here is different. When running `user.items.myscope.to_a` I get the following result missing the aggregate values and adding an id field that should not be there.

```
[
  #<Item:0x00000103cc3d38> {
      :id => nil,
    :date => Thu, 23 Jan 2014
  },
  #<Item:0x00000103cc39a0> {
      :id => nil,
    :date => Wed, 22 Jan 2014
  }
]
```

How it would be possible to pass the aggregate functions to the scope?

Comment: I may be way off but I recall having to wrap the aggregate field names in quotes, EG `select("sum(item1_count) as 'sum_item1'")`

Comment: Tried that but doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Have you tried actually calling the aggregate method on an object to check if it's there? (Like `Item.first.sum_item2`) I just did a quick test and even though the object inspector doesnt print out aggregate fields, they're there and calling their method returns the correct value.